# How to change select order in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like follows.

```
A
--
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

When I get data as follows

```
select A from table
```

it returned as follows

```
A
--
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

But my desired result is as follows.`first:c`,`second:d` and then order remaining element.

```
A
--
c
d
a
e
f
```

Is there any way to change order as I want?

Comment: sorry `A` is column name, thanks

Comment: You have to add an `ORDER BY` clause that describes the order you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The trick we'll use is ordering by two fields. The first field we'll order by will be a conditional - explicitly telling postgres to put `c` first and `d` second. After that, we'll order by the regular column.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY 
  CASE mycolumn WHEN 'c' THEN 0 WHEN 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
  mycolumn;

 mycolumn
----------
 c
 d
 a
 b
 e
 f
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit arbitrary?

Comment: Well, yes, but the question is a bit arbitrary. Unless I misunderstood it.

Comment: Yes, the question is unclear. Such questions should be closed.